# The best Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sending form data to db with UPDATE query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET price = '100-200' WHERE login = '$login'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET city = '$city' WHERE login = '$login'");
```

My question is: how to rebuild it to have query which writes data in db, but do not remove older posts.

For example: If user enters data 'price' and 'city', and after this, he wants to change only 'city', script with update will cancel 'price' and leave blank field in db.

How to make it to update (like in example) only city, but to leave price as it was before (100-200). Is there a proper query for this?

Comment: Just don't run the second update statement if you don't need it :S

Comment: why dont you just surround the `mysql_query` with an `if($price){`?

Comment: Avoid using mysql_ and move on to mysqli. Also make sure to filter / santitize your inputs, otherwise you're leaving a big hole open for sql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do a check for `NULL` or empty variables before running the SQL Statements. Something like this:

```
if(!empty($price))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `price` = '".$price."' WHERE `login` = '".$login."';");
}
if(!empty($city))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `city` = '".$city."' WHERE `login` = '".$login."';");
}
```

Comment: Thank's, I think this is solution which I expected.

Comment: use empty instead of is_null and checking for an empty string [link](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php)

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks, couldn't remember the command, was still thinking in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

use "INSERT INTO `table` (column1, column2,column3) VALUES (val1,val2,val3)";

ps: mysql_* is deprecated update to PDO or MySQLi

Comment: then add the user id as a column in the query and mysql

Comment: The question is about updating, not inserting.